# Should there be a community wiki for information about whether the bootloader can be unlocked on a particular device?

Tags: discussion

Similar to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) for information on how to root different devices, should a community wiki exist for whether the bootloader can be unlocked on different devices and how this is achieved?

Just thought it may gather information in one place.

Comment: Sounds good to me. If you do so, please do not forget to link to it from our `bootloader` tag wiki, so it's easily be found :)

Comment: @Izzy I'll go ahead and create a question. I have knowledge about a limited number of devices, so hopefully people can chip in what they know...

Comment: They certainly will. We can deal with that as with the rooting one: Whenever a question turns up for a certain device not yet listed, link it from there. As with the rooting question, the (only) answer should contain nothing but links to the corresponding questions, and one such question allowed per device. Multiple questions for the same device getting closed as dupes. My 2 ¢ at least :)

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm slightly stuck as to what to put to start the question and answer... All I've got is a disclaimer. Do you have a better idea as of what to do?

Comment: Might I suggest using a pastebin (or some place for "collaborate editing"), then link to it from chat and continue there? For the disclaimer etc., you could also check the rooting tag-wiki. You might also consider waiting a little to get a few more opinions first; just me thinking it's a great idea doesn't exactly make a majority :)

Comment: Perhaps leave it for a bit then and see what others think, especially seeing as I haven't got much of a clue as to what to do at then moment... Thanks for the info

Comment: I'd have a pretty clear idea about it (see my answer and upvote it if you agree / downvote if not). But we should wait for consent before starting anything.

Comment: Would you mind starting the community wiki if other people like this idea? Your answer seems like a good place to start; pretty similar to the rooting one but that's a good thing

Comment: Sure thing, I'd do it. As it's a community wiki, I'd put up the question and start the answer – where you could chime in then and fill the gaps. Deal? :)

Comment: Sure. I'll add what I know.

Comment: What's happening with this suggestion? Could someone possibly open a question with a community wiki answer so that people could add this information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can deal with that as with [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575):

- collect existing questions, and link them from the answer – one per device
- list should be ordered alphabetically, grouped by manufacturer
- Whenever a question turns up for a certain device not yet listed, add the link
- Whenever a question turns up for a device already listed, VTC as duplicate to the existing one

As with the rooting question, the (only) answer should contain nothing but links to the corresponding questions, and one such question allowed per device. Exceptions might be considered when a newer Android version requires a different approach.

PS: We should link to that question then from our [bootloader](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootloader) tag-wiki, to make it easy to find.

Comment: Per your suggestion, are we allowed to add those questions where OP asked for rooting method and got an answer which instructed bootloader unlocking? We don't receive many explicit bootloader unlocking questions, I believe.

Comment: @Firelord I'd say everything giving the solution is valid. If the linked question is about rooting+unlocking, a comment next to the link could state that.

Comment: Let's make sure that questions primarily about rooting are only included where there's explicit, detailed, obvious instructions about unlocking the bootloader. If there are then certainly, we should add that as a solution.

Comment: @LJD200, that can be considered a possibility but we need to sketch it out on Meta, since  your expectation for *explicit, detailed, obvious instructions* would differ from mine and mine from Izzy's, and Izzy's from an another user and so on. Absence of clear guidelines would make things very unclear and may result in rolling back edits.

Comment: From the seeker's standpoint, "all information available" would be of interest. We could have 2 answers: One with *explicit, detailed, obvious instructions*, and another with *helpful but partly incomplete hints*. Explicit questions for "how to unlock" should not be closed as dupes to those "posts having some details as side effect to their main part" then. I.e., in the 2nd answer, there could be links to multiple posts per device.

Comment: Definitely would like to see it materialise.  Being "End user" site, by itself is reason to have this available, popularity of such query need not be a factor

Comment: @beeshyams then upvote this answer :) That's how voting on Meta works: upvote = agree, downvote = disagree. Has nothing to do with rep here.